# How to google all sites that use particular wiki engine

Tags: google-search

I know that Google has [code search](https://code.google.com/) that helps to find something within code.

I wonder if there is any way to get list of sites that uses particular engine?

For example find all sites that use **XWiki** engine or **MediaWiki** engine?

I know that sources of this opensource projects here:

http://svn.wikimedia.org/

https://github.com/xwiki

And Google Code Search searches within them. But I was looking for a way to list sites that use this engine.

Can anyone advise me? Could it be that there is some other search service that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Google Code provides code project hosting. It's search engine only searches the content that resides in its own repository; it doesn't search content in hosted in other sites.

Comment: @Rubén ok, but any ideas how i can find what i need?

Comment: See http://www.powersearchingwithgoogle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not provide the complete list of wiki sites on the Internet as some wiki sites are private and configured to be not indexed.

You can get an idea of the numbers with nerdydata.com.

---

XWiki

> [Search `<link rel="alternate" type="application/x-wiki"` in nerdydata.com](https://search.nerdydata.com/code/?and_code%5B%5D=%3Clink+rel=%22alternate%22+type=%22application/x-wiki%22&limit=0,10)
>
> 23,595 result

MediaWiki

> [Search `<meta name="generator" content="MediaWiki` in nerdydata.com](https://search.nerdydata.com/code/?and_code%5B%5D=%3Cmeta%20name=%22generator%22%20content=%22MediaWiki&limit=0,10&rank_min=1&rank_max=1000001)
>
> 49,526 result

---

Related: [Is there a search engine for web sites html/js code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20533988/1608670)